# Extend nuxt 2 plugin

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js

What is the best way to extend a plugin in nuxt? I have a plugin file that is very long. I want to add functionality, but keep the new code in a different file.
This is what I have so far, but I don't have access to the context this way. This is necessary as I need to access other plugins.

```
import { newCode } from './newStuff.js

export default (context) => {
    const myPlugin = {
        install: (Vue) => {
            Vue.prototype.$module = {
            // ... existing code
            }

             Object.assign(Vue.prototype.$module, newCode) 
        }
    }

Vue.use(myPlugin)
}
```